# Is this first order logic representation correct?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

I need am going through one online video for First Order Logic,

the statement to convert in FLO is

> Everyone loves its mother.

The instructor writes it like this

```
(For All x)(There exists y) Mother(x,y) and Loves(x,y)
```

If x is person1,person2,person3, it will work fine.

However if x is table, it won't work. So using For all X does not seem right to me,here. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, the instructor assumed that the domain is only humans. Ofcourse, what you are saying is correct. Other statements should be added e.g. Person(x) and Person(y) to make this more specific.

Comment: if there is no universe defined the assertion must be general

Answer (score 0):

you are right, the mistake is in (there exist y) because if x is a table does not exist a mother. I think the correct answer may be

```
(For All x)(for all y)(if Mother(x,y) than Loves(x,y))
```

or, just tobe sure to be understood

```
(For All x)(for all y)(Mother(x,y) --> Loves(x,y))
```

It means that for every x and y (even for tables) if y is the mother of x than x loves his mother, that is the assertion you had in the beginning.

Where is the artificial intelligence part?

(Sorry for my english)